# How to configure Composite C1 to serve .m and desktop as the same site

Tags: azure, c1-cms

I have a new starter Mercury site installed on azure.
I have edited the site.
On my pc the site appears as per the edits.
On my phone the site appears as it's original state after installation.
I believe this is because on my phone there is a setting to prefer mobile sites, which will request the .m sub domain automatically.
I haven't setup multiple sites, this is a simple, new azure web app, default composite install with the mercury starter kit.

How do I configure composite to serve the same site to both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a split between mobile and desktop content, where desktops will get the animated multi-paged jumbotron, while mobiles will get a simpler jumbotron.

Currently you can change the mobile content if you go here in the C1 Console: "Layout | Page Template Features | Front Page Content Start" and edit this.

Given this feedback we will probably move the block to the actual front page content, so it is much easier to find.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Yes I am definitely saving and publishing. The browser running on the PC picks up the change but the phone does not. I have refreshed and cleared history etc, everything I can think of. But if I simply say prefer desktop version voila it appears correctly. Swap the phone back to prefer phone version and "Welcome to Mercury" re-appears? the site is here zangl.azurewebsites.net  I'll look into bootstrap a little more to see if the problem is with bootstrap. Many Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the answer - there is indeed a mobile/desktop content split at play. See answer and sorry for the inconvenience.